# Set textContent of an element with PHP SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

PHP `SimpleXMLElement` can access XML and also give me the text content of an element with the implicit string cast conversion. But I see no way to change that text content. Is it possible?

I have this XML:

```xml
<root>
    <element>text</element>
</root>
```

The text in the element can be accessed like this:

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
$element = $xml->xpath('/root/element');
echo $element;
```

But what I also need is setting the text so that the XML looks like that:

```xml
<root>
    <element>new text</element>
</root>
```

```php
$element = 'new text';
```

This obviously doesn't work. But I don't even know what to try. It's not documented and I couldn't find anything on the web. A class that makes me search so much for simple usage can't be "simple".

The JavaScript equivalent would be:

```js
element.textContent = "new text";
```

Comment: `echo $element;` would print "Array". Have you tried `var_dump($element)`?

Comment: Oh I get the impression that I should just forget `SimpleXMLElement` and rather use `DOMDocument` which looks more solid and usable.

Comment: @brombeer Maybe it's an array, then I mean to use its first element. My real code looks different than this basic example.

Comment: @brombeer Nope, that has no effect. And it's not documented either. How did you invent it?

Comment: The call to `xpath` will return an array of elements, so that's the first thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```php
   $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<root><element>text</element></root>");
   $element = $xml->xpath('/root/element');
   $element[0][0] = "new text";
   echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Cool, that works. What is that special `[0]` there? Why does it act like the DOM's `textContent` property?

Comment: It's just the weird way SimpleXML elements are structured:

var_dump($element);

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      public 0 => string 'new content' (length=11)

Comment: Guess it doesn't come out that pretty as a comment...  Try  var_dump($element) and you'll see.

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed weird. Eventually, I'm parting ways with SimpleXMLElement, it can't move an element from one document to another. That class seems to be tailored to a very specific and limited use case, it's completely rubbish for generic XML manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML is limited.

PHP supports DOM and Xpath. Xpath is actually a little easier to use - compared to the browser. `DOMXpath::evaluate()` returns a list of nodes or a scalar value depending on the expression.

```php
$xml = '<root><element>text</element></root>';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath();

// fetch and iterate nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(/root/element)[1]') as $element) {
    // modify node
    $element->textContent = "new text";
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Comment: That's what I did now. I also had to move nodes from one document to another (using `importNode`), which seems completely impossible with SimpleXMLElement.